# how to cite the report in the text in APA format?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

how to cite the report in the text in APA format?

http://www.irena.org/DocumentDownloads/Publications/IRENA_RE_Power_Costs_2014_report.pdf

For example, In research you write (Ahmed, 2014) in the end of paragraph (APA format).

What will be case in the case, If I take one paragraph from the IRENA report. How i will in-text citation in the end or beginning of paragraph.
www.irena.org
irena.org

Comment: How are you creating your bibliography?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the document does not work. If it is available only  you might want to use the `@online` entry type, there is also `@report`. Aha! Found and added the link. The even have on the first page "This publication should be cited as: IRENA (2015), *Renewable Power Generation Costs in 2014*.". So just out `IRENA` into the author field, the title is clearly `Renewable Power Generation Costs in 2014`, date/year is `2015` (January 2015, if you want to be more precise), add the URL for your readers' convenience and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using BibTeX, I suggest you use the catch-all entry type `@misc` in the `.bib` file:

```
@misc{irena:2015,
   author = "{International Renewable Energy Agency}",
   title  = "Renewable Power Generation Costs in 2014",
   year   = 2015,
   month  = "January",
   note   = "\url{http://www.irena.org/DocumentDownloads/Publications/IRENA_RE_Power_Costs_2014_report.pdf}"
}
```

Note that the author is a so-called *corporate author*. Be sure to have loaded the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages in order to enable the macro `\url`.

The formatting of this entry will depend crucially on the bibliography style file you choose. (If you haven't already chosen a bibliography style, you may want to start with the style `apalike`.) The formatting of the citation call-outs to this entry will depend both on the bibliography style in use and on any citation management packages (e.g., `natbib`) you may have loaded. If the `natbib` package is loaded and if you have a lot of citations to this piece, you could, for instance, define a citation alias as follows:

```
\defcitealias{irena:2015}{IRENA}
```

You could then write `\citetalias[p.~105]{irena:2015}` to generate the call-out "IRENA (p. 105)".